# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val'

Tags: python, binary-tree

I was having an attribute error. line 24, in emptyOutTree
if currentNode.left != None and currentNode.left.val not in removed:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val'
I just started python and can't seem to figure out why I keep getting this error. I have pasted my code and commented for line 24

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val, left = None, right = None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def emptyOutTree(rootNode):
    if rootNode == None:
        return []
    else:
        queue = []
        queue.append(rootNode)
        while len(queue) > 0:
            removed = []
            currentNode = queue.pop(0)
            if currentNode.left == None and currentNode.right == None:
                removed.append(currentNode.val)
            else:
                if currentNode.left != None and currentNode.left.val not in removed: #line 24
                    queue.append(currentNode.left)
                if currentNode.right != None and currentNode.right.val not in removed:
                    queue.append(currentNode.right)
            print(removed)
                
root = TreeNode(1,1)
root.left = TreeNode(2,2)
root.left.left = TreeNode(4,4)
root.left.right = TreeNode(5,5)
root.right = TreeNode(3,3)



emptyOutTree(root)
#printTree(root)
```

Comment: E. g. in `root = TreeNode(1,1)` what should the second `1` mean?

Comment: that second one is just to set its value as per the constructor

Comment: No, the first one is `val`.  The second one becomes `left`, which makes no sense.

Comment: Also, you're inconsistent about what sort of items should be in the `removed` list.  In most cases it looks like that list should contain TreeNode objects, but then you also have `removed.append(currentNode.val)` which adds a plain integer.

Comment: appreciate the help that second value was the issue. New to python learning it as I go for the first assignment for a class (:. Also that is the only line that adds to removed - its the queue that takes nodes. I want to print the leafnodes that were removed so to do that I'm just going to print the removed array and have that holds nodes values

Comment: Voting to close this question. If you have a new question, ask a new one.